# Prove $G\cong H\oplus \Bbb{Z}^{k}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be an abelian group and let $H$ be a subgroup. Let $G/H\cong \Bbb{Z}^{k}$. Prove $G\cong H\oplus  \Bbb{Z}^{k}$.

What I did so far is: there is an epimorphism from $G$ to $\Bbb{Z}^{k}$ such that $H$ is the kernel,$f$. $H$ is abelian and therefore $H\cong \Bbb{Z}_{P1}\oplus...\oplus \Bbb{Z}_{Pn}. $ Since $G/H\cong \Bbb{Z}^{k}$ then $f(g)=(a_1,...,a_k)$ for every $g\in G$. Let $h\in H$, then $f(h)=(0,..,0)$. Let us look at $\Bbb{Z}_{P1}\oplus...\oplus \Bbb{Z}_{Pn}\oplus \Bbb{Z}^{k}$. $H\cong \Bbb{Z}_{P1}\oplus...\oplus \Bbb{Z}_{Pn}$ and $G/H\cong \Bbb{Z}^{k}$ and since $\Bbb{Z}_{P1}\oplus...\oplus \Bbb{Z}_{Pn}\cap \Bbb{Z}^{k}=\emptyset$, we get $|\{H\cap G/H\}|=|G|=|H|\cdot | \Bbb{Z}^{k}|$

This is where I got. If I can prove $G/H$ is  isomorphic to a sugroup $N$ such that $N$ and $H$ are disjoint I am done. How can I take it from here?

Comment: Why "...and therefore $\;H\cong\Bbb Z_{p_1}\oplus\times\oplus\Bbb Z_{p_n}\;$ " ?? Who said $\;H\;$ is torsion?

Comment: Aren't abelian groups product of cyclic grips ?

Comment: it may well depend on what you understand by "product". For example, what kind of "product" you think the abelian additive product of the reals is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea: let $\;X:=\{h_i\;:\;\;i\in I\}\;$  be a generator set of $\;H\;$, and let $\;\{g_1+H,..,g_k+H\}\;,\;\;g_i\in G\;$ be a *free* generator set of $\; G/H\;$

== Show that $\;x\in\langle g_1,...,g_k\}\cap\langle X\rangle\implies x=0\;$

== Show that $\;\langle\{ g_1,...,g_k\}\cup\{ X\}\rangle=G\;$

Answer (score 1):

Use free groups are projective. Theres a short exact sequence $0\to H\to G \to \mathbb Z^k\to 0$ that splits.

Comment: It may well that projective groups/split short exact sequences is beyond the OP's reach right now, yet this is the shortest past almost surely.

Comment: Anyway you don't need the notion of ‘projective’: $\mathbf Z ^k$ is a *free* abelian group (which is within the O.P.'s grasp, I guess), and $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbf Z ^k,G)\simeq G^k$ so it's easy to construct a section $\mathbf Z ^k\rightarrow G$.

Comment: @Bernard Yes, sure. I'm on my phone so I had to be succinct.